# oc4j jstl db connectivity problem

Tags: jsp, jstl, compatibility, oc4j, oas

I have OAS version 10.1.3.3 and the applciation that uses jstl 1.1. in tomcat (where it works fine) does nto work fine in OAS.

To use jstl 1.2 requires jsp 2.1 and servlet 2.5. Does OAS 10.1.3.3 support this? I tried to find online for this compatibility but could not confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably need to configure OC4J to use JSTL:

- Unzip `jakarta-taglibs-standard-1.0.zip`, the file downloded from Apache to a directory, say `D:\mydir`.
- Copy the files in the directory `D:\mydir\jakarta-taglibs\jstl-1.0\lib` to `<J2EE_HOME>\default-web-app\WEB-INF\lib`. If the directory `<J2EE_HOME>\default-web-app\WEB-INF\lib` is not present, create it.
- Copy the file `JstlSql.jsp` to the directory `<J2EE_HOME>\default-web-app\examples\jsp`
- Run it from `http://<host-name>:<port>/examples/jsp/JstlSql.jsp`

Source: ["How to use SQL JSP Standard Library"](http://www.oracle.com/technology/sample_code/tech/java/codesnippet/jsps/jstlsql.html) ([google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:67k_DXvwio0J%3awww.oracle.com/technology/sample_code/tech/java/codesnippet/jsps/jstlsql.html+jstl+oc4j&cd=2&hl=ru&ct=clnk&gl=ru)).